# Install folder under /var/log in Python setup script

Tags: python

I am looking to create a folder under /var/log for my python script on installation so my python daemon can write its logs to it. For disutils, I have seen that there is this kind of feature I want but for files

- [Installing Package Data](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data)
- [Installing Additional Files](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files)

but I am not sure if it works for folders. Is there a similar feature or way for me to this for folders? or maybe I am not looking at the problem the right way and I just need to create the directory itself when I initialize my logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the folder under /var/log from my python script but. Did some checking first before creating:

```
if not os.path.exists("/var/log/folder"):
    os.makedirs("/var/log/folder")
```